# Bazel glib cc_library results in undefined symbols when used from go_library

Tags: go, bazel, cgo

I'm trying to get my Go application building with Bazel. I initially tried using gazelle to generate my BUILD files and this mostly worked but it doesn't really handle CGO at all.

Specifically I'm trying to use govips https://github.com/davidbyttow/govips which provides Go bindings for libvips, a popular image processing library.

I have created the following cc_library targets for libvips and libglib which it depends on. On macOS I have installed these packages with homebrew which places them under opt/homebrew. On linux, I'll use Alpine's package manager which should install them under usr/.

```
load("@rules_cc//cc:defs.bzl", "cc_library", "cc_import")

cc_library(
    name = "libglib",
    deps = [
        ":libglib_headers",
        ":libglib_lib_headers",
        ":libglib_library",
    ],
    visibility = ["//visibility:public"],
)

cc_library(
    name = "libglib_headers",
    hdrs = select({
        "@bazel_tools//src/conditions:darwin": glob(["opt/homebrew/include/glib-2.0/**/*.h"]),
        "//conditions:default" : glob(["usr/include/glib-2.0/**/*.h"]),
    }),
    includes = select({
        "@bazel_tools//src/conditions:darwin": ["opt/homebrew/include/glib-2.0/"],
        "//conditions:default" : ["usr/include/glib-2.0/"],
    }),
    strip_include_prefix = select({
        "@bazel_tools//src/conditions:darwin": "opt/homebrew/include/glib-2.0",
        "//conditions:default" : "usr/include/glib-2.0",
    }),
    deps = [
        ":libglib_lib_headers",
    ],
)

cc_library(
    name = "libglib_lib_headers",
    hdrs = select({
        "@bazel_tools//src/conditions:darwin": glob(["opt/homebrew/lib/glib-2.0/include/*.h"]),
        "//conditions:default" : glob(["usr/lib/glib-2.0/include/*.h"]),
    }),
    includes = select({
        "@bazel_tools//src/conditions:darwin": ["opt/homebrew/lib/glib-2.0/include/"],
        "//conditions:default" : ["usr/lib/glib-2.0/include/"],
    }),
    strip_include_prefix = select({
        "@bazel_tools//src/conditions:darwin": "opt/homebrew/lib/glib-2.0/include",
        "//conditions:default" : "usr/lib/glib-2.0/include",
    }),
)

cc_import(
    name = "libglib_library",
    shared_library = select({
        "@bazel_tools//src/conditions:darwin": "opt/homebrew/lib/libglib-2.0.dylib",
        "//conditions:default" : "usr/lib/libglib-2.0.dll",
    }),
)
```

```
load("@rules_cc//cc:defs.bzl", "cc_library", "cc_import")

cc_library(
    name = "libvips",
    deps = [
        ":libvips_headers",
        ":libvips_library",
    ],
    visibility = ["//visibility:public"],
)

cc_library(
    name = "libvips_headers",
    hdrs = select({
        "@bazel_tools//src/conditions:darwin": glob(["opt/homebrew/include/vips/*.h"]),
        "//conditions:default" : glob(["usr/include/vips/*.h"]),
    }),
    includes = select({
        "@bazel_tools//src/conditions:darwin": ["opt/homebrew/include/"],
        "//conditions:default" : ["usr/include/"],
    }),
)

cc_import(
    name = "libvips_library",
    shared_library = select({
        "@bazel_tools//src/conditions:darwin": "opt/homebrew/lib/libvips.dylib",
        "//conditions:default" : "usr/lib/libvips.dll",
    })
)
```

My Go target looks like:

```
load("@io_bazel_rules_go//go:def.bzl", "go_library", "go_test")

go_library(
    name = "vips",
    srcs = [
        "arithmetic.c",
        "arithmetic.go",
        "arithmetic.h",
        "color.c",
        "color.go",
        "color.h",
        "composite.go",
        "conversion.c",
        "conversion.go",
        "conversion.h",
        "convolution.c",
        "convolution.go",
        "convolution.h",
        "create.c",
        "create.go",
        "create.h",
        "draw.c",
        "draw.go",
        "draw.h",
        "error.go",
        "foreign.c",
        "foreign.go",
        "foreign.h",
        "govips.c",
        "govips.go",
        "govips.h",
        "header.c",
        "header.go",
        "header.h",
        "icc_profiles.go",
        "image.c",
        "image.go",
        "image.h",
        "label.c",
        "label.go",
        "label.h",
        "lang.go",
        "lang.h",
        "logging.go",
        "math.go",
        "morphology.c",
        "morphology.go",
        "morphology.h",
        "resample.c",
        "resample.go",
        "resample.h",
        "stats.go",
        "test_resources.go",
    ],
    cgo = True,
    cdeps = [
        "@libglib//:libglib",
        "@libvips//:libvips",
    ], # keep
    importpath = "github.com/attilathefun/govips/v2/vips",
    importpath_aliases = ["github.com/attilathefun/govips/vips"],
    visibility = ["//visibility:public"],
    deps = [
        "@org_golang_x_image//bmp",
        "@org_golang_x_net//html/charset",
    ],
)
```

When I try to build my Go target with bazel, I get this undefined symbols error:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:
  "_g_object_get", referenced from:
      _load_buffer in 000024.o
      _save_buffer in 000024.o
  "_g_object_unref", referenced from:
      __cgo_e76c63319f27_Cfunc_g_object_unref in 000004.o
      _embed_multi_page_image in 000020.o
      _embed_multi_page_image_background in 000020.o
      _extract_area_multi_page in 000020.o
      _load_buffer in 000024.o
      _save_buffer in 000024.o
      _clear_image in 000027.o
      ...
     (maybe you meant: __cgo_e76c63319f27_Cfunc_g_object_unref)
  "_g_type_check_instance_cast", referenced from:
      _embed_multi_page_image in 000020.o
      _embed_multi_page_image_background in 000020.o
      _extract_area_multi_page in 000020.o
      _set_jpegload_options in 000024.o
      _set_pngload_options in 000024.o
      _set_webpload_options in 000024.o
      _set_tiffload_options in 000024.o
      ...
  "_g_type_check_instance_is_fundamentally_a", referenced from:
      _clear_image in 000027.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture arm64
```

From the suggestion it looks like the symbol names might be getting mangled by bazel?

> (maybe you meant: __cgo_e76c63319f27_Cfunc_g_object_unref)

Do you have any ideas of what might be causing this / how I might be able to resolve it?

The same Go module works fine with go build.